# Handling expression differently for display vs. calculation?

Tags: evaluation, output-formatting

I have a function I wrap a lot of my numbers with to factor them and display them out a certain way. Usually I do this at the last step of a calculation, but sometimes it would be nice if I could designate that a number should be displayed one way, but handled another way for computation.

For example, suppose I wanted prime numbers in some list to be printed out bold. I might do that with:

```
nums = If[PrimeQ@#, Style[#,Bold], #]& /@ nums
```

The problem is that if I then want to, say, take all the elements in that list that are under 100, any code that hits `Style` instead of a number will freak out.

Is there something like a wrapper that designates an expression to be handled as some value for subsequent evaluation, but print out a certain way when it comes to display preparation? I know you could achieve this by messing with `$PrePrint`, but it seems like there might be a better way.

Comment: Have a look at [Interpretation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpretation.html?view=all)

Comment: @JasonB. That doesn't work if you put the Interpretation wrapped numbers in a variable. Try `nums = Interpretation[If[PrimeQ@#, Style[#, Red], #], #] & /@ 
  Range[15]` and then `2*nums`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tried to do this before and found it ultimately to be a complex problem.  Certainly there are easier ways to accomplish specific tasks, such as what Bob Hanlon showed, but that doesn't actually provide the functionality requested.

I believe you will need to choose either a "whitelist" or "blacklist" approach to how functions handle your wrapper.  For example we could use UpValues (created with [`TagSetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html)) to tell all functions besides [`If`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html), [`List`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html), and [`MakeBoxes`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes.html) to strip the wrapper. (These specific functions only because I need them for the example to function.)

Foundation:

```
MakeBoxes[hiddenStyle[x_, sty__], _] := ToBoxes @ Style[x, sty]

p1 = Except[If | List | MakeBoxes];

hiddenStyle /: (h : p1)[a___, hiddenStyle[x_, __], b___] := h[a, x, b]
```

Usage:

```
nums = If[PrimeQ@#, hiddenStyle[#, Red], #] & /@ Range[15]
2*nums
```

[image]

Here you see that your style is applied (by way of the [`MakeBoxes`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes.html) definition), but arbitrary functions outside of our `p1` pattern see the wrapper `hiddenStyle` as transparent. This is only a minimal working example and is not intended to be robust.

The other approach is to overload each function that you want to use to see the wrapper as transparent.  For example we could write:

```
ClearAll[hiddenStyle]
p2 = Plus | Times | Power;
MakeBoxes[hiddenStyle[x_, sty__], _] := ToBoxes @ Style[x, sty]
hiddenStyle /: (h : p2)[a___, hiddenStyle[x_, __], b___] := h[a, x, b]

nums = If[PrimeQ@#, hiddenStyle[#, Red], #] & /@ Range[15]
2*nums
foo /@ nums
```

[image]

With more work it is possible to create more complex behaviors such as passing on styling to output, but they often come at a significant cost of performance, e.g. interfering with [`Listable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) behavior.

If you describe your application in more detail I can try to provide additional examples.

Answer (score 5):

Using `$PrePrint` is fairly easy.

Define a helper function to use with `$PrePrint` to deconflict multiple uses of `Slot (#)`

```
boldPrime = If[PrimeQ[#], Style[#, Bold], #] &;

$PrePrint = If[Head[#] === List, boldPrime /@ #, #] &;
```

`boldPrime` is mapped onto lists

```
nums = Range[25]
```

[image]

`nums` can be used subsequently

```
nums^(1/2)
```

[image]

```
RandomInteger[{0, 100}, 20]
```

[image]

It is not mapped onto other forms of expressions

```
3 x^5
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Why not create a form wrapper to output primes in bold? For example:

```
MakeBoxes[myForm[expr_],StandardForm] ^:= Internal`InheritedBlock[{MakeBoxes},
    MakeBoxes[i_Integer,StandardForm] := If[PrimeQ[i], StyleBox[ToString[i],Red], ToString[i]];
    MakeBoxes[expr]
]

Unprotect[$OutputForms];
$OutputForms = DeleteDuplicates[Append[$OutputForms, myForm]];
Protect[$OutputForms];
```

(I used red instead of bold so that the difference is a bit more noticeable). Then:

```
foo /@ Range[10] //myForm
```

[image]

Because `myForm` is a member of `$OutputForms`, the `myForm` wrapper gets stripped before getting stored in `Out`:

```
%//InputForm
```

> {foo[1], foo[2], foo[3], foo[4], foo[5], foo[6], foo[7], foo[8], foo[9], foo[10]}

Copy/paste of will also strip the `myForm` wrapper.